# Process.start works from VS but no window on published executable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run an external program with some arguments (visual basic) and it was running all fine when executed from Visual studio Debug, but when using Release from visual studio or the published version(debug or release) there are no windows and the processes are running in Task Manager.

I tried this to modify the `workingdirectory` and `windowstyle` ProcessStartInfo properties with no results, that solved the similar cases asked here. In the task manager the opened program seems to stay "Under" my program in hiearchy vs when executed from VS ( not sure if that helps)

```
    Dim startinfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    startinfo.FileName = slicerexepath
    startinfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(slicerexepath)
    startinfo.Arguments = arglist
    startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Process.Start(startinfo)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross check your "slicerexepath" is same for debug and release modes . In usual practice, release and debug exe are kept in separate path .

Comment: Saw it late but that was it, a different version of the program which is still surprising because even that other version worked fine on debug, for some reason became picky with release